# legends on seaborn kde plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I can't figure out how to put legends on a seaborn kde plot.

```py
uses = df.primary_use.unique()
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax = plt.axes()
plt.legend(uses)
for use in uses: 
    sns.kdeplot(df[df['primary_use'] == use]['wind_speed'], ax=ax)
```

see the output here:

[image: link_to_image]

`uses` array looks like:

```sh
array(['Education', 'Lodging/residential', 'Office',
       'Entertainment/public assembly', 'Public services'], dtype=object)
```

`uses` is what the legend is supposed to be but it puts `wind_speed` for each plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using the `label` parameter:

```
for use in uses: 
    sns.kdeplot(df[df['primary_use'] == use]['wind_speed'], ax=ax, label=use)
```

My MCVE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], 100), data=np.random.randint(0,100,(100)))
df=df.rename_axis('use').reset_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
use=['a','b','c']
for u in use:
    sns.kdeplot(df[df['use'] == u][0], ax=ax, label=u)
```

Output:

[image]